# excute the image magic commands with php

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert pdf to image so that install the image magic and ghost script.when i run command "convert file.pdf image.png" into terminal then work file but when i run in exec using php show me error in apache log "/var/root/Desktop/ImageMagick-6.6.4/bin/convert: Permission denied".I install php in Mac.in my php file i give the perfetc path also as exec("/var/root/Desktop/ImageMagick-6.6.4/bin/convert ".getcwd().'/'."filename.pdf[2] ".getcwd().'/'.$filename).

have dream day

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this usually relates to the fact that apache is executed as a different user than the one you use to execute the command manually.   You will have to change permissions or ownership of the source and destination files in a way that will allow the apache user (probably www-data)  to read and write the data. (and execute convert)

Comment: Hi, I have given the 777  permission to  files,also when i excute the 'whoami' command then show me the nobody.what is means.

Comment: hi,I can convert the image  files but not pdf to image, means error is in ghostscript,do you have any idea? I want to convert the pdf  to images?I  can convert using the terminal but not with exec,

Comment: DONE-there was problem with the plugin install on server,now works  fine